# How to Access Lamp www Folder In Network

Tags: networking, server, apache2, samba, lamp

I was working on windows where I had simple file sharing I had 1 PC where I installed WAMP for Web development I was working in simple Work group  I had my all project in www folder like site1 site2 site3 I can delete and edit these folder and could do access simple writing my PC name like my-pc/site1 or my-pc-site2 in browser ..

Actual Problem :

Then I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my PC I installed LAMP apache2 phpmyadmin and SAMBA server  I shared www folder on network when I type in my windows PC my ubuntu machine name like ubuntu-pc or 127.0.0.1 I can only see default www directory default page then I created virtual host like site1.com and site2.com but I'm unable to access site1.com and site2.com From my windows7 PC how can I access my all project In workgroup? I can access phpmyadmin of Ubuntu PC only folder can't access or virtual hosts

---

In site-enabled folder 3 files are placed `000-default.conf` `example.com.conf` and `test.com.conf`. I can access all these 3 folders index.php inside the ubuntu machine only default site can access outside ubuntu but when I'm trying to access  test.com or example.com it opens google page or I try `smb://test.com:8080` I can modify folders and its file too from Win7 because I allowed permission 777 R

---

I have created samba share point /var/www ... I want to access all website project from windows PC that I created in ubuntu localhost Folder I was typing Pc-ip/site.com but now I tried `smb://Pc-ip/site-name` this also doesn't work for me samba service and apache2 also running I can access all site places in www folder inside ubuntu machine

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I can only guess.
But what are the permissions in your www-folder, especially if you are sharing them with samba and edit them on another pc (Windows?!) with a specific user?

what does your apache 2 conf files look like? Especially the ones in

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
```

#### edits to specify questions:

Given your answer, there are several things I do not understand:

is your problem that you cannot open the different websites from other PCs in your homenetwork?

Did you create a samba share that points to your www folder? (Maybe add contents of /etc/samba/smb.conf

Can you browse and modify files in this share from another PC?

How are you browsing the share? (smb://your-servers-ip/sharename should do the trick, however, I do not understand why you add the port '8080'. This seems odd to me).